# How to filter by derived facets in algolia

Tags: algolia

Given the following indices:

```
{
    id: 1,
    distance: [4, 10]
},
{
    id: 2,
    distance: [1, 2]
},
{
    id: 3,
    distance: [9, 10]
}
```

After enabling faceting on `distance` to be able to apply numerical filters on it, I want to apply additional filtering on a derived attribute that I'll call `distance_range`. It derives its value through custom logic on an existing attribute for example:

```
// In JS:
distance_range: Math.floor(( distance - 0.5 ) / 5) * 5 + "-" + Math.ceil(( distance ) / 5) * 5
```

Which would transform each distance number into a range "0-5", "5-10", etc.

```
{
    id: 1,
    distance: [4, 10],
    distance_range: ["0-5", "5-10"]
},
{
    id: 2,
    distance: [1, 2]
    distance_range: ["0-5"]
},
{
    id: 3,
    distance: [9, 10]
    distance_range: ["5-10"]
}
```

What is the best way to arrive at such an index? Do I have the process the data beforehand, or does algolia have such a feature to transform attributes on the fly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algolia uses a custom data structure to index your data in order to deliver results as fast as possible.
Rebuilding an index in real-time would be too long to get an answer, which is why, even for sorting, Algolia [requires you to duplicate your data into multiple indices](https://www.algolia.com/doc/relevance/sorting#sort-by-an-attribute).

If you only had to compute the new attribute for display, it would definitely be achievable with front-end logic, both [autocomplete.js](https://github.com/algolia/autocomplete.js) and [instantsearch.js](https://community.algolia.com/instantsearch.js/documentation/) have a method to transform the data before displaying it.

However, since you want to filter on it, Algolia needs this information in the data structure, so you'll have to do this computation beforehand.
Also, don't forget to add this new attribute to [`attributesForFaceting`](https://www.algolia.com/doc/ruby#param-attributesForFaceting).